# How can i get the timeout from a request in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, timeout

How can I get the timeout of it?

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=1)
```

Comment: what do you mean "get" the timeout of it?

Comment: Like a seconds time response from my pc to the url

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following idea:

In the header attribute of the request you can get the date when the request was made.

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', headers=headers)

r.headers #return something like that: 

{'Date': 'Mon, 31 May 2021 19:18:48 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '32', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'gunicorn/19.9.0', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'}
```

And you can acces to the date with the next line:

```
r.headers['Date']
```